# Add a Seed List to Journey Builder Send

Tags: journeybuilder, marketing-cloud

I'm wanting to add a seed list (staff of my organisation) to a journey builder send. Does anyone know how to do this? I know how in Content Builder, but can't find the same functionality in Journey Builder.
Thanks
Annie

Answer (score 1):

I do this by creating one data extension with all my target subscribers and seeds in it using SQL with a union (and I have Automation Studio refresh this daily). For example:

```
select
Id,
Email,
FirstName,
LastName,
Gender
from DATA_EXTENSION_A
WHERE Email IS NOT NULL 
union
select
Id,
Email,
FirstName,
LastName,
Gender
from DATA_EXTENSION_B_SEED_LIST
where Email is NOT NULL
```

This will only work if your source of entry is a data extension though.

Answer (score 0):

Journeys were created to trigger a series of messages with decision-tree activities, so a BCC or additional "lists" were not put into the platform as a feature.. but, you could try:

1. Adding to your Journey Entry criteria so internal folks will be eligible to enter.
2. Control how often they enter the Journey based on that data or Journey Settings.

Good luck!